# Find by encrypted value Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using Doctrine, Symfony and this: https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle

How do I use the orm like

```
->findOneByUsername('username')
```

if username is @Encrypted (stored as 'blob' in mysql)? If I look at the query in the log file it seems to not encrypting the value before adding it to the sql query...

Comment: Well then, show, how you call encryption on your query parameters.

Comment: I guess that DoctrineEncryptBundle is doing that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar the `https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle` but as you can see in the source, there is a `ambta_doctrine_encrypt.encryptor` service.

So I would guess you can load the service and encrypt the condition value manually before running `findOneByUsername`.

Try something like this:

```
// or where ever your container is located.
$encryptor = $this->container->get('ambta_doctrine_encrypt.encryptor');
```

And then do:

```
->findOneByUsername($encryptor->encrypt('username'));
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This is a good idea but unfortunately the encryptor does not generate the same cipher on every call.